# xor function in python

Tags: python, xor

I'll be happy if someone can help with XOR function in python.

for example, I have two quite big messages (about 300 symbols) that is writteb by hex code
how can I XOR them properly?
I tried use general functions and converted to another types, but I wasn't able to do that(

I don't know which type of data I need to convert for?

Comment: Can you please clarify, the "symbols" in the messages are in hex in text, i.e. strings like `"46 6f 6f"`?

Comment: right, there it is -->>  e877a5e68bea88d61b93ac5ee0d562e8e9...

Comment: 1. It looks like you're trying to do crypto. Use an existing crypto library instead of rolling your own. 2. What are your inputs and desired outputs? What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate over the string chars, then convert each char to int (`int(a,16)`), then apply xor, reconvert to hex with `hex`, strip the leading '0x' with `[2:]`, and finally join everything

```
stra = 'abc'
strb = 'abd'
''.join(hex( int(a,16) ^ int(b,16) )[2:] for a,b in zip(stra, strb))
```

Note that, as pointed in the comments, it will work only if the two strings have the same length. Otherwise some chars of the longer string will be ignored.

Comment: Won't this break if the two strings have unequal lengths?

Comment: It depends on what you call break :). `zip` will return tuples only for the minimum length of its parameters. `zip('abc','ab')` is `[('a', 'a'), ('b', 'b')]`

Comment: I'd call ignoring part of one of the values "broken".

Answer (score 6):

If I get your question correctly, if you have 2 hex numbers represented as string:

```
a = "e877a5e68bea88d61b93ac5ee0d562e8e9"
b = "23fe3231699ade23482"
```

you can xor any of them with some mask, by converting to int, and applying bitwise xor operator:

```
xor_result = int(a, 16) ^ int(b, 16)

print '%x' % xor_result
```

and, if you want to keep the original format

```
string_xor_result = hex(xor_result)[2:]
```

Comment: The best way to find out is to try, but python has arbitrary precision ints, so it should be ok.

Comment: As Xavier said, python can handle very, very large integers (the only limit comes from the machine available memory), so a 300 digits hex number (~16 ** 300) isn't a problem.

Comment: I'd up-vote this if it included converting the result back to a string of hex digits...

Comment: by the way, does it appropriate to strings with differents lengths? –

Comment: @user1813163, yes, technically the shorter string (smaller number) will be prepending with leading zeroes.

Answer (score 1):

If two strings do not have the same length you can add one line, cycle()

```
stra = raw_input("msg: ")
strb = raw_input("key: ")
strb = cycle(strb)

print ''.join(hex( int(a,16) ^ int(b,16) )[2:] for a,b in zip(stra, strb))
```